# How to conditionally format test based on status of a form?

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, conditional-formatting

I am trying to get my form to show red text when the form is invalid and green when the form is valid based on the status of the form and the validation criteria. How can this be achieved through angular 8?

(HTML)

```html
   <p class="status">
   Form Status: {{ Form.status }}
   </p>
```

(TS)

```
      Form = this.fb.group({
        Id: [0],
        name: ['', Validators.required],
        app: ['', Validators.required],
        domain: [''],
        environment: ['']
         })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create invalid-class CSS and adjust your html to:

```
<p class="status">
   Form Status: 
   <span [class.invalid-class]="Form.invalid">
      {{ Form.status }}
   </span>
</p>
```